# How to use multiple conditions in Mongoose and express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend

I coded my backend to search for mongoose schemes that match two of my conditions. So, I got two request parameters and used those parameters in my find() or findOne() query. However, I get data which only matches one of my conditions. What is wrong with my code? I tried three methods that are written on StackOverflow, and all three returned the same result.

```
router.get("/:date/:type", getMeal)
```

First Method of Finding:

```
const meal = await Meal.find({ $and:[{type: req.params.type}, {date: req.params.date}]});
```

Second Method of Finding:

```
const meal = await Meal.findOne({'type': req.params.type, 'date': req.params.date});
```

Third Method of Finding:

```
const meal = await Meal.where("date")
  .equals(req.params.date)
  .where("type")
  .equals(req.params.type);
```

At my backend localhost, it returns like below picture.
[image]
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do all 3 queries return the same exact result from the database? or is your image from the 3rd Method?

Comment: @Woodsy All 3 queries return the same exact result from the db, the last one.
Nothing matches the two parameters, so it is supposed to return a empty array.